# C# - How to compare two different text files

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In the case that there were two text files:

```
FileA.txt
test
1234
testing


FileB.txt
test
5667
pond
```

and all occurrences in FileA.txt would be removed from FileB.txt, being output into FileC.txt

So FileC.txt would read:

```
5667
pond
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problems have you encountered? What research have you done? This isn't a place to just come looking for someone to do your homework.

Comment: Can you give more details surrounding your requirements?  Do you care about duplicates, ordering, etc?

Comment: why is this closed?  it's pretty clear what is being asked here

Comment: I agree with @Robert, closing this as "not a real question" is IMHO an abuse of the close voting system. Fair enough, we don't like "send me teh codez" type questions, so downvoting is fine. But closing as "not a real question" is not - especially when the OP is a newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines("FileC.txt",
  File.ReadAllLines("FileB.txt").Except(File.ReadAllLines("FileA.txt")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string fileA, fileB, fileC;
var result = File.ReadAllLines(fileB).Except(File.ReadAllLines(fileA));
File.WriteAllLines(fileC, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your text files are formatted, but you can use StreamReader to load and read through the lines of the text.  First, do that to A, add each line to an array, and then filter through the array for each line of B to see if there is a match.  If so, remove that line from B before creating C with StreamWriter.

Read about streamreader [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader).  Read about streamwriter [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter).